# Scripts Time is showing AM, but it's PM

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time

I have a script that enters the current time when a column is checked. It was working well, but now it's showing the time in AM and it's actually PM. ie: Currently when I fill it in the time in LosAngeles is 9pm, but it is showing as 9am. I checked the timezones and they appear to match. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  checkinTimeStamp(e);
}

function  checkinTimeStamp(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=s.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var timezone = s.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "hh:mm");
  data.forEach(function(row,col){
    if (col == '') return;     
    if (row[0] == '') return;  
    if (row[1] != '') return   
    sheet.getRange(col + 1,1).clearContent();
  });
  data.forEach(function(row,col){
    if (col == '') return;    
    if (row[1]== '') return; 
    sheet.getRange(col + 1,1).setValue(timestamp);
  });
}
```

[Example Spreadsheet]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120weviA4z2jOqEWQXlwx_zioK1iSczwpcWuLQKUW4tA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

In your script, how about following modification?

#### From:

```
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "hh:mm");
```

#### To:

```
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "HH:mm");
```

or

```
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "hh:mm a");
```

- `h`: Hour in am/pm (1-12)
- `H`: Hour in day (0-23)
- `a`: Am/pm marker

#### References:

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)